# How to use Cloud Functions for Firebase to write a SOAP service?

Tags: web-services, firebase, soap, google-cloud-functions

I need to implement an soap web service using firebase functions.
I found a module called soap-node [soap-module-github](https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap) which seems promising, since it integrates with express, and firebase says it uses express for http calls, but the problem, is I don't know how to integrate that module with firebase functions since, firebase functions are the handler of the http calls made by the clients, any help would be very helpfull.

Here is the code I have managed to create so far:

```
    var fs = require('fs'),
    soap = require('soap'),
    express = require('express'),
    lastReqAddress;
    var server = express();
    service = {
        StockQuoteService: {
            StockQuotePort: {
                GetLastTradePrice: function (args, cb, soapHeader) {
                    if (soapHeader)
                        return {
                            price: soapHeader.SomeToken
                        };
                    if (args.tickerSymbol === 'trigger error') {
                        throw new Error('triggered server error');
                    } else if (args.tickerSymbol === 'Async') {
                        return cb({
                            price: 19.56
                        });
                    } else if (args.tickerSymbol === 'SOAP Fault v1.2') {
                        throw {
                            Fault: {
                                Code: {
                                    Value: "soap:Sender",
                                    Subcode: {
                                        value: "rpc:BadArguments"
                                    }
                                },
                                Reason: {
                                    Text: "Processing Error"
                                }
                            }
                        };
                    } else if (args.tickerSymbol === 'SOAP Fault v1.1') {
                        throw {
                            Fault: {
                                faultcode: "soap:Client.BadArguments",
                                faultstring: "Error while processing arguments"
                            }
                        };
                    } else {
                        return {
                            price: 19.56
                        };
                    }
                },

                SetTradePrice: function (args, cb, soapHeader) {},

                IsValidPrice: function (args, cb, soapHeader, req) {
                    lastReqAddress = req.connection.remoteAddress;

                    var validationError = {
                        Fault: {
                            Code: {
                                Value: "soap:Sender",
                                Subcode: {
                                    value: "rpc:BadArguments"
                                }
                            },
                            Reason: {
                                Text: "Processing Error"
                            },
                            statusCode: 500
                        }
                    };

                    var isValidPrice = function () {
                        var price = args.price;
                        if (isNaN(price) || (price === ' ')) {
                            return cb(validationError);
                        }

                        price = parseInt(price, 10);
                        var validPrice = (price > 0 && price < Math.pow(10, 5));
                        return cb(null, {
                            valid: validPrice
                        });
                    };

                    setTimeout(isValidPrice, 10);
                }
            }
        }
    };
    var wsdl = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/../wsdl/stockquote.wsdl', 'utf-8').toString();
    server = express();

    soapServer = soap.listen(server, '/stockquote', service, wsdl);
```

here is the stockquote.wsdl:

```
<wsdl:definitions name="StockQuote"
         targetNamespace="http://example.com/stockquote.wsdl"
         xmlns:tns="http://example.com/stockquote.wsdl"
         xmlns:xsd1="http://example.com/stockquote.xsd"
         xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
         xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">

<wsdl:types>
   <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://example.com/stockquote.xsd" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema">
       <xsd:element name="TradePriceRequest">
          <xsd:complexType>
              <xsd:all>
                  <xsd:element name="tickerSymbol" type="string"/>
              </xsd:all>
          </xsd:complexType>
       </xsd:element>
       <xsd:element name="TradePrice">
          <xsd:complexType>
              <xsd:all>
                  <xsd:element name="price" type="float"/>
              </xsd:all>
          </xsd:complexType>
       </xsd:element>
       <xsd:element name="TradePriceSubmit">
           <xsd:complexType>
               <xsd:all>
                   <xsd:element name="tickerSymbol" type="string"/>
                   <xsd:element name="price" type="float"/>
               </xsd:all>
           </xsd:complexType>
       </xsd:element>
       <xsd:element name="valid" type="boolean"/>
   </xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>

<wsdl:message name="GetLastTradePriceInput">
    <wsdl:part name="body" element="xsd1:TradePriceRequest"/>
</wsdl:message>

<wsdl:message name="GetLastTradePriceOutput">
    <wsdl:part name="body" element="xsd1:TradePrice"/>
</wsdl:message>

<wsdl:message name="SetTradePriceInput">
    <wsdl:part name="body" element="xsd1:TradePriceSubmit"/>
</wsdl:message>

<wsdl:message name="IsValidPriceInput">
    <wsdl:part name="body" element="xsd1:TradePrice"/>
</wsdl:message>

<wsdl:message name="IsValidPriceOutput">
    <wsdl:part name="body" element="xsd1:valid"/>
</wsdl:message>

<wsdl:portType name="StockQuotePortType">
    <wsdl:operation name="GetLastTradePrice">
       <wsdl:input message="tns:GetLastTradePriceInput"/>
       <wsdl:output message="tns:GetLastTradePriceOutput"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="SetTradePrice">
        <wsdl:input message="tns:SetTradePriceInput"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="IsValidPrice">
        <wsdl:input message="tns:IsValidPriceInput"/>
        <wsdl:output message="tns:IsValidPriceOutput"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>

<wsdl:binding name="StockQuoteSoapBinding" type="tns:StockQuotePortType">
    <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="GetLastTradePrice">
       <soap:operation soapAction="http://example.com/GetLastTradePrice"/>
       <wsdl:input>
           <soap:body use="literal"/>
       </wsdl:input>
       <wsdl:output>
           <soap:body use="literal"/>
       </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="SetTradePrice">
        <soap:operation soapAction="http://example.com/SetTradePrice"/>
        <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:input>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="IsValidPrice">
        <soap:operation soapAction="http://example.com/IsValidPrice"/>
        <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:input>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>

<wsdl:service name="StockQuoteService">
    <wsdl:port name="StockQuotePort" binding="tns:StockQuoteSoapBinding">
       <soap:address location="http://localhost:5002/stockquote"/>
    </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

I have googled very good I just don't find some path , I also searched google functions and their integration with soap, since firebase functions are just google cloud functions used for firebase

Comment: did you find the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Peeking at the source code for `node-soap`, you should be able to directly pass the `_requestListener` to the Cloud Function's `onRequest` function:

```
exports.stockquote = functions.https.onRequest(soapServer._requestListener)
```

Comment: i've tried this and get error `cannot read property 'log' of undefined`

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right path,

If you want the your GCF Path for the server to be `http://myfunctions.domain.com/stockquote/`

then your last line in the js file should be
`soapServer = soap.listen(server, '/', service, wsdl)` and then after that, in your Google Cloud Function `index.js` enter:

`exports.stockquote = functions.https.onRequest(server)`

You will have to make sure that your SOAP requests are going the endpoint **with** a trailing slash at the end. If you do not have control of the existing clients then you can add in your own URL handler that will look at the URL and add a `/` to the URL that your function received.

i.e.:
`exports.stockquote = functions.https.onRequest( gcfURLHandler(server) );`

where `gcfURLHandler`is defined as

```
function gcfURLHandler( handler ){
    return (req, res ) => {
        if( !req.url || !req.path ) {
            req.url = "/" + (req.url || '');
        }
        handler( req, res )
    }
}
```

figured this out from a comment [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/27#issuecomment-341253842). (which also has other tips in the original code)

I was working on this last week and saw the unanswered question. Took a lot of digging around to finally figure it out. Hopefully this helps others looking to do the same!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `express` with cloud functions now :

```
server = express();
server.listen(5002, function () {
  soap.listen(server, '/stockquote', service, wsdl);
});

exports.stockquote = functions.https.onRequest(server);
```

Put the route in firebase.json :

```
 "rewrites": [
   {
    "source": "/stockquote",
    "function": "stockquote"
   }
 ]
```

When testing on the client using javascript don't forget to change the endpoint to override `localhost` in wsdl :

```
var soap = require('soap');
var url = 'https://[your-project-id].firebaseapp.com/stockquote?wsdl';
var args = {tickerSymbol: 'some symbol', price: 100.0};

var options = {
    'endpoint' : 'https://[your-project-id].firebaseapp.com/stockquote'
};

soap.createClient(url, options, function(err, client) {
    if (err) throw err;
    //print service in json
    console.log(client.describe());
    client.GetLastTradePrice(args, function(err, result) {
        if(err)
            console.log("err = "+ err.message);
        console.log(result);
        res.status(200).send(result);
    });
});
```